# How to redirect a page after few minutes?

Tags: php, html, session

I want to redirect a page after 10 minutes and clear the session values.
I achieved this using the code.Any page in my website will get redirect after 10 minutes

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT="600;URL=logout.php?timeout">
```

In my logout.php page I have the code for clearing session values and redirect to index.php page.But now I get only redirect to index.php page and session value is not destroy.

```
       <?php
       session_start();
       // remove all session variables
       session_unset(); 

       // destroy the session 
       session_destroy(); 
       echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
       window.location.href='index.php';
       </SCRIPT>"); 
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this by using refresh header the in php
like

```
<?php
     /*in this refresh is in second you can define it as your requirement*/
     $sec=6000;
     header( "Refresh:$sec; url=http://www.example.com/page2.php", true, 303);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems correct and it should work. You can add the line

```
$_SESSION = array();
```

somewhere between `session_start()` and `session_destroy()` just to be sure the session variables are wiped. It shouldn't be needed, this is what `session_destroy()` is supposed to do.

If it still doesn't work then use `print_r($_SESSION)` to be sure the session is properly set in `logout.php`.

Comment: <?php
       session_start();
       // remove all session variables
       session_unset(); 
  $_SESSION = array();
       // destroy the session 
       session_destroy(); 
 /*       echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
       window.location.href='index.php';
       </SCRIPT>");  */ If I commented redirecting code session value is cleared nw.

Comment: You can also try to clear the session cookie, as described in the example #1 on the documentation page of [`session_destroy()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php).

Comment: I cant use header to redirect